# Move files to multiple directories

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the below cmd line which moves the dll files from one folder to another.

```
for /r "myoldfolder" %x in (*.dll) do copy "%x" mynewfolder /y
```

How can I make it look to a destination of not just mynewfolder but all the directories listed by the "`where python`" command?

Comment: You mean the directories containing all instances of programs that satisfy `where python` - there is a difference here

Comment: No, sorry. If I execute where python in cmd, it gives me a list of the locations of all executables. I want those to be used.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but if I understand correctly, You will need to also loop through the destinations of `where python` and then using variable expansion to get the drive and path only. I.e `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where python') do echo %%~dpi`